How to make SQLDelight use sqlite3 directly via JNI on Android?
We have database with big blobs (images) ~3.5mb which we cannot read on Android versions below 9 (API 28) because we cannot set a larger custom cursor window size (see https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/pull/4804).
For Android SQLDelight has AndroidSqliteDriver class which uses Cursor under the hood with window size limitations, while there are no such limitations for native sqlite3 queries.
How can I make SQLDelight use sqlite3 API directly via my custom JNI wrapper? Should I write a custom driver class? If yes how can I do this? My thought was to write my own driver based on AndroidSqliteDriver just replacing Cursor calls with JNI calls, but unfortunately I do not know how to do it properly, can you give an example of such implementation?
SQLDelight discussion https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/discussions/5250

"Should I write a custom driver class?" -- probably. "can you give an example of such implementation" -- I doubt that there is one. However, you could look at Requery's SQLite wrapper and see how they do JNI calls for SQLite. In their case, they are using their own packaged copy of SQLite binaries.

The design by itself is questionable, because there is no SQL server involved and the backend therefore will be the file-system anyway.  It's not alike read from RAM, write to NIC.

Android (last I checked) does not let you link directly to the sqlite3 on the device. That's why there's no "SQLiter" for Android (disclaimer: I wrote SQLiter, which provides the native driver for SqlDelight).
You might want to look at SqlCipher.
https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher.
It provides its own Android driver. If you don't give it a key, it'll act like the regular sqlite. I don't know if they have a way to specify the cursor window size, but if not, you'd have a much easier time forking that than starting over.
Alternatively, the KMP Room implementation seems to have a new driver on the Android side, although I haven't had much time to dig into it and confirm that.
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room
